# Number of elements in $\{g\in G|g^k=e\} \leq k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be cyclic and of order $n$. I would like to show that given $k\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, the number of elements in $\{g\in G|g^k=e\}$ is less than or equal to $k$.

I am not really sure how to prove this but I noticed that $S=\{g\in G|g^k=e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. For, take $x,y\in S$.As $G=<g>$ for some $g$, $(xy)^k=(g^ig^j)^k=g^{(i+j)k}=e$. Similarly $x^{-1}$ is in $S$.So, $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ and so $S$ is cyclic. So, we can write $S$ as $<h>$ for some $h\in S$. Also, by lagrange's theorem, $|S|$ divides $G$.
Also, let $h=g^r$.Then $o(h)=n/(n,r)$. Since $h^k=e$, $g^{rk}=e$ i.e. $n|rk$.
$\exists x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx=rk$. So, $S=o(h)\leq n/r=k/x\leq k$.

Could anyone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: It is true that $\{g\in G|g^k=e\}$ is a subgroup but your proof that it is a subgroup is incorrect. It is not true that for all $x,y\in G$ you have $(xy)^k=e$.

Comment: @uniquesolution, sorry I meant $x,y \in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H = \{ g\in G | g^k = e\}$. $H$ is subgroup of $G$, so $H = \langle x \rangle$, for some $x \in G$. The order of $x$, $r$ divides $k$, because $x^k = e$, hence $r \leq k$. Now you can say that $r = |H| \leq k$.